# Is it possible to use tail and grep in combination?

Tags: linux, grep, pipeline, tail

I am trying to tail a user in production log.

Is it possible to use

```
tail -f grep "username"
```

Comment: Maybe `tail [...] -f | grep username`

Comment: It's a little more efficient to use `tailf` instead of `tail -f`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes - You use pipe. i.e.

```
tail -f <some filename> | grep 'username'
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can just use a pipe

tail -f fileName | grep username

Comment: Either use `tailf` or `tail -f`.

Answer (score 3):

The `ack` command, which is a grep-like text finder, has a `--passthru` flag that is designed specifically for this.

Since `ack` automatically color codes matches for you, you can use it to search the output of a tailed log file, and highlight the matches, but *also* see the lines that don't match.

```
tail -f error.log | ack --passthru whatever
```

All the lines of the tailed log will show up, but the matches will be highlighted.

ack is at http://beyondgrep.com/

Answer (score 1):

factually I have found it to be more efficient to use:
grep username filename | tail